# JavaFX - Adding extra starting parameters

Tags: java, javafx

I worked with JavaFX because I had to programm an "interactive shell". I already programmed the Class Shell which connects to the remote host via SSH.

But the Shell has three parameters in his constructor:

```
public Shell(String username, String password, String host) {

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.host     = host;
}
```

And what I would need (or would be perfect):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage,String username, String password, String host) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.shell = new Shell(username,password,host);
    initialiseOverview();
}
```

Is there any way I could add extra/optional starting Parameter to the JavaFX start method. Or is there any other way how I could handle this problem?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is your issue? Why can you not do just this? Just be sure to also call your `super.start(primaryStage)` to additionally call the method you are overriding.

Comment: I already tried that but it seems like JavaFX's start method only allows one Stage as an parameter. The Error I got: The type ShellBoard must implement the inherited abstract method Application.start(Stage) @MattClark

Comment: `start()` is basically the first method in your JavaFX application that is executed. It is called automatically by the startup process (i.e. you never call it yourself). Where are you expecting to get the values for `username`, `password`, and `host` from?

Comment: The programm will be executed multiple times on a Windows Server 2012 R2. So multiple bash skripts will execute my Java file multiple times with different SSH parameters. @James_D

Comment: So these are being passed to the Java application as command line parameters?

Comment: Yes, thats how it is planned. @James_D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the command line parameters with [`Application.getParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    Application.Parameters parameters = getParameters();
    List<String> rawParams = parameters.getRaw();
    String userName = rawParams.get(0);
    String password = rawParams.get(1);
    String host = rawParams.get(2);
    this.shell = new Shell(username,password,host);
    initialiseOverview();
}
```

This code assumes there are (at least) three command line parameters. You probably want to add checks for the number of parameters and show an error message or prompt if they are missing, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. That will solve my problem. :) @James_D